# loading png from json file using PIL

Tags: python, json, png

I am trying to use PIL.Image.open to open the image from an opened json file. Should I just put the name of the png file inside the Image.open() or is it the directory that leads to the json file?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your existing code, a sample of the JSON file and any other details that may be relevant.

Comment: _Should I just put the name of the png file inside the Image.open() or is it the directory that leads to the json file?_ Isn't that the kind of thing which would be covered in the documentation?

Comment: @zzzhang, you might want to be *clearer* as to what you are looking for. Yes, you place the path to the png file inside of the open method. It is covered in the Pillow docs [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/Image.html#open)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a full example which is probably what you're looking for:

```
    import json
    from PIL import Image
    
    with open('yourfilename.txt', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    
        # Load the file path from  the json
        imgpath = data['yourkey']
        
        # Place the image path into the open method
        img = Image.open(imgpath)
```

The `imgpath` variable should return a string of the path to your image.

[Pillows Image.open docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/Image.html#open)

Comment: This is where I am at right now but it keeps saying there is no such file for 'mykey'

Comment: You will need to give us your code sample because it's pretty hard to debug otherwise -as @Selcuk mentioned above. :)

Comment: oh i found my error, it is just my path is not correct.